XMLHttpRequest blocked by CORS policy (tomcat 9)
I would like to send an XMLHttpRequest in an HTML page using JavaScript.
Unfortunately it fails because of this message:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:15067/my/app' from origin 'http://localhost:1180' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access -Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
I set the CORS filter on the tomcat web server as follows:
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>http://localhost:1180</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
    <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Access-Control-Allow-Origin</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials,Access-Control-Allow-Methods,Access-Control-Allow-Origin</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
    <param-value>180</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

I also tried a "*" in the "cors.allowed.origins" parameter without success.
Is there another way to solve this error?

There is a typo here, <init param> should be <init-param>

@Mina You're right, but in my web.xml it is correct. Seems to be a copy&paste mismatch!?

[so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [sf] would be better places for questions like this.
